# trouble to handle batch file in c#

Tags: c#, process

my code is :

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"batchfile.bat";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "some argument";
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.Start();
StreamReader sr = myProcess.StandardOutput;
textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

it works but i want to get asynchronous output.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to enable asynchronous read operations on `StandardOutput`.

To start asynchronous read operations, you must redirect the `StandardOutput` stream of your batch, add an event handler to the `OutputDataReceived` event, and call `BeginOutputReadLine`. Thereafter, the `OutputDataReceived` event signals each time the batchwrites a line to the redirected `StandardOutput` stream.

You will finc a complete example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`Process` class also exposes a StandardInput property that allows you to send a command to the standard input of the process.

You may find [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/468480/Csharp-Command-Prompt-class) helpfull.